# bash $1 parameter amnesia during calls to other executables

Tags: macos, bash

Under OS X, I have a bash shell script which takes a parameter (which is a folder name)

when I call:

```
echo "Build Starting for $1" | tee ~/MyFolder/$1/build.log
```

It works right. It echos the right "$1" parameter into the ~/MyFolder/$1/build.log file (which exist). However, when I call another executable and trying to make use of the $1 parameter, the parameter is always empty.

```
xcodebuild -configuration Release -project MyProject.xcodeproj | tee -a ~/MyFolder/$1/build.log
```

this creates "build.log" in "~/MyFolder" and the $1 is ignored.

Why is that? Do I need to "export" it somehow?

Comment: Those look the same to me - you say they're in the same script?  Can you show us some more context?

Comment: yes. same script. line after line. the only difference is "echo" is a bash command, and "xcodebuild" is probably another script that runs as a sub-process.

Comment: But the `tee` is executed by your script.  What `xcodebuild` is makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're calling a function or another script and want the same $1, $2,.. to be available, use:

```
myFunctionOrScript "$@"
```

`"$@"` is equivalent to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`, and will thus make sure "$1" in the subprocess is the same as "$1" in the parent process.

You can also assign their values to new, named variables:

```
export mydir=$1
```

and then use `$mydir` in place of `$1` in subprocess scripts.

Comment: Not relevant to the OP's question.

Comment: It would seem the $1, $2, $3, ... parameters are not exported by default and are not available to sub processes. How do I export them? export $1 or export $1=$1 did not work.

Comment: You can't export $1, $2, $3, because they're special parameters. You can, however, explicitly pass them along to subprocesses to make sure that "$1" in the subprocess is the same as "$1" in your parent process. That's what the answer does. If you don't want to do that for some reason, you can work around it by export mydir=$1 and then use "$mydir" in place of "$1" in subprocesses.

Comment: that worked nicely. @thatotherguy, if you post this as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: I added the suggestion of exporting the variable with another name to this answer.